# How can I measure Number of Items with over X amount of sales?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI database set up as follows:
Sales[Date] is the date in which the sale took place. Sales[ProductID] is the SKU, while Sales[Units] is the number of units sold per SKU. I have also added a measure to calculate the total # of units sold. I am trying to set up a distinct count of SKUs where more than 500 SKUs were sold. I am using the following formula:

SKUsWith500Sales = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[ProductID]),FILTER(Sales,[TotalUnits]>=500))

The output is either blank or inaccurate.

Thank you!

Comment: This DAX looks pretty solid.  What is the visual where it's showing up 'blank or inaccurate'

Comment: Using the card visual. For example, right now it is telling me there are 16 SKUs with more than 500 sales, while there are really 29.

Comment: I'd move it into a table and start putting slices on there, looking for some kind of pattern that might show what records aren't behaving as expected.  Also, us TotalUnits on your Sales table?  If not, review the relationships between the table as this can be a source for 'extra' records.